# How can I break out of a while loop, from within a nested case statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In the script below - which prompts the user to confirm that they want to proceed with running a potentially bad script - when the user enters `Y` at the prompt - it will break out of the `case` block, only to be sent back into the `while` loop again.

```
#! /bin/bash
set -e

echo
echo "bad install start"
echo "-----------------------------------------"

while true; do
        read -p "this script will probably fail - do you want to run anyway?" yn
        case $yn in
                [Yy]*)
                        ##### WHAT GOES HERE?? #####
                        ;;
                [Nn]*)
                        exit ;;
                *)
                        echo "answer y or n" ;;
        esac

        echo "script has broken out of case back into while loop"
done

echo -e "\e[33m Installing bad packagename \e[0m"
apt-get install sdfsdfdfsd

echo "rest of script - will i keep running?"
```

When `n` is entered, the script exists entirely as desired. I'd like to know how to make it so that when `Y` is entered the script breaks out of both the `case` **and** the while block, but does not exit entirely. Is there something I can put in for the placeholder ("What goes here??") to do that?

Comment: Note that first `[Yn]*)`; you probably meant `[Yy]*)`.

Comment: You edited your code since I first answered, but note in any case that `$TEST=1` should be `TEST=1`, and your script is very likely to work with this change.

Comment: doh, yes I saw that when testing!

Comment: @dhag I think I've improved upon your edit—please take a look. It seems your goal is to rewrite the code into something where your accepted answer fits well, and I think it's closer now.

Comment: @derobert: Your edit looks fine to me; it certainly makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the case where the user entered "y", you can exit both while and case:

```
break [n]
       Exit from within a for, while, until, or select loop.  If  n  is
       specified, break n levels.  n must be ≥ 1.  If n is greater than
       the number of enclosing loops, all enclosing loops  are  exited.
       The  return  value is 0 unless n is not greater than or equal to
       1.
```

In your case, you want to do `break 2`.

Comment: thanks, yes `break 2` did it, regarding your comment above, yes I tried setting a variable, but it didnt work - Im guessing bash has local scope within while and case blocks? unlike , for example PHP

Comment: No, bash variables aren't local (unless you explicitly declare them so), so assigning to TEST within the `case` as you did should be reflected in the test for the while loop.

Comment: ah got it, I was performing another assignment inside the `[Yy]` case block. made a little edit inside my question to reflect, but  your right it works - thanks I learnt a couple of cool things!

Comment: In that case, `break` is enough. I don't see two levels of loops in the code.

Comment: @xhienne: You appear to be correct! I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

@dhag has a great answer. You can also use:

```
a=0
while [ "$a" -eq 0 ]; do
     ...
     [Nn]*)
          a=1;
          ;;
      ...
done
```